# hexagonal holes on gyroid surface/mesh imported as obj file

Tags: modeling

I imported a gyroid surface mesh (obj) generated in another program (Mathmod).
I am trying to make create hexagonal holes like here

[image]
[image]

I tried Tissue plugging but the results are not similar.
It would be nice if someone can guide me in the right direction where I can define the hexagonal hole size.

I am getting hexagonal mesh but with varying sizes of hexagons. I like to have the same size.
[image]

Also after applying the wireframe modifier I am not getting exactly flat faces. i think this can be achieved mostly using bevel modifiers but not able to set the correct limit method/parameters.
[image]

Comment: Can you show your current result? Why the results are not similar? The holes doesn't look more esagonal than circular or octagonal....can you sketch a piece of topology of the mesh you have in mind?

Comment: I updated my results in the question and also closer view of the expected pattern.

Comment: Would it be possible to share a (at least) a portion of the object to allow users to have a closer look?

Comment: @Timaroberts do you mean the blend file? the reference 3D model can be seen here https://www.bathsheba.com/math/gyroid/